# How can I get a custom eslint rule to do context.report without having a node?

Tags: javascript, rule, eslint

I want a very simple eslint rule that ensures that the top line of every file says 'ouch'. Something like this seems to work - but how do I context.report it without a node? or how can I get a node which is the first line of the file to use?
Should I be using a callback declared on an event in the 'return' instead (if so, which event)?
Thanks!

```
'use strict';
function checkFirstLine (context) {
    if (context.getSourceCode().lines[0] !== 'ouch') {
        // How do I context.report without a node?
    }
}

module.exports = {
    meta : {
        docs : {
            description : 'check first line',
            category : 'Possible Errors',
            recommended : true
        },
    },
    create : function (context) {
        checkFirstLine (context);
        return {};
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it out, I can use:

```
context.report(context.getSourceCode().ast, 'Cripes');
```